# Following a CiviCRM checksum link doesn't populate civicrm tokens but logging in populates the tokens.

Tags: tokens, user-account, checksum

Example use case:

You want to link a user to a page and populate some information about them (e.g. display an online membership card):

[current-user:civicrm-contact:display-name]
[current-user:civicrm-contact:custom-122]

These tokens do not populate following a checksum link but do populate when the user logs in.  Is there an easy way to make the checksum link behave in the same way as logging in for the purpose of these tokens?

Answer (score 2):

1. I assume the "page" you're referring to is using a Webform, If that's the case, then you should mention that in the title.
2. The link to the form should be of the format `http://example.com/your_form?cid={contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum}`.
3. On the CiviCRM tab, in the Contact Field section, select Existing Contact, as well as all the fields you want to appear on your Webform.

Comment: The page could be a webform as you suggest, but that is irrelevant as the question is about how to get the current-user civicrm-contact tokens to work, rather than use civicrm webform to add civicrm fields to a form. 

The easiest way I have found is to log a user in from a checksum link, but that is a bit riskier than just displaying information without access to the rest of the user's account.